# Angular: Or operator inside of a h2 tag?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<div *ngIf="domain || library">
    <!-- <h2>{{ domain.catergory | uppercase }} || {{ library.name | uppercase }}</h2> -->
    <h2>{{ domain.catergory | uppercase }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ library.name | uppercase }}</h2>
<div>
```

New to Angular, javascript, html. I'm wondering if syntax wise, is it possible to use the "||" OR operator inside of a  tag to display information. I commented it out because it did not work for me, but the uncommented code works but that's not the functionality I want. It displays both names at the same time or sometimes it just displays the "domain.catergory".

Comment: || in yours is just text, not an OR

Comment: Why don't you use the `*ngSwitch` directive?

Comment: What is the desired functionality?

Comment: @BShaps the desired functionality is display some names from two different arrays.

Comment: It would be helpful if you put in a couple examples of what the desired output is. For example, if both domain.category and library.name are given, do you want both or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide or show the content by using ng-container elements. Refer code snippet below:

```
<div>
    <ng-container *ngIf="domain">
        <h2>{{ domain.catergory | uppercase }}</h2>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="library">
        <h2>{{ library.name | uppercase }}</h2>
    </ng-container>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding an *ngIf for each h2 as in

```
<h2 *ngIf="domain?.catergory">{{ domain.catergory | uppercase }}</h2>
<h2 *ngIf="library?.name">{{ library.name | uppercase }}</h2>
```

Notice the question mark after domain and category. That way you ensure no runtime errors will appear in case domain or library variables don't exist